# Android - Layout scrolling with a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scroll

My app has a profile page. In that page, I have profile and header photos. And have a `ListView` at below.

My `ListView` scrolls correctly but not `RelativeLayout` which contains profile and header photos.

I can't wrap the whole xml with `ScrollView` because I have `ListView` at there. It's not reasonable solution.

I want to make the whole page scrollable. I want photos behave like they are items in `ListView`.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** Of course I looked for it but couldn't find any significant solution. Neither Google nor Stackoverflow could help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the profile and header photos in a relative layout.  Change the ListView to a LinearLayout and wrap it all in a ScrollView. Does this work?

Comment: But when I change ListView to a LinearLayout how do I fill it with textboxes easily like setting ListView's array adapter? I could have to use for loop right?

Comment: yeah, a loop works. it's a pretty simple procedure. just keep doing lView.addView(txtBox) for each TextBox...

Answer (score 0):

overwrite ListView or GridView

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(  
               Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);  
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
}
```

that you can write ListView in ScrollView
try it

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can add listview in a scroll view, and your profile and listview both will scroll but it is neither recommended nor it will show same behavior on all devices.

I think, what you can do is use Expandable listView having 1 parent (which will contain profile+pic) and many children. Here your each listview item will become 1 child. Make child View of expandable listview always visible. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can include you headers and profile photos too in your ListView. Basically, you can have a listview with multiple rows with different completely different layouts. Override the methods getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position in your Adapter. This should start you off in the right direction.